# How to replace using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I have a XML document and I need to replace

```
<json type="array">
```

for

```
<m:telemoveis xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:m="http://www.projetoPei.com/Main"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.projetoPei.com/Main Main.xsd">
```

I tried the following FLOWER expression but the double quotes appear as &quote ; .What am I doing wrong?
Also how can i use the value of new-name instead of m after the return?

```
for $x in doc('FnacData.xml')/json
let $new-name :=" m:telemoveis xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot;xmlns:m=&quot;https://www.projetoPei.com/Main&quot;xsi:schemaLocation=&quot;https://www.projetoPei.com/Main Main.xsd&quot;"
return 
    element m   {

        $x/*
    }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output? I'm not quite sure that I understand what you are trying to achieve. Also, are you trying to persist this change in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Why you creating element in variable?

Can you smiply use like below:

```
for $x in doc('FnacData.xml')/json 
return 
<m:telemoveis xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://www.projetoPei.com/Main" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.projetoPei.com/Main Main.xsd">
{$x}
</m:telemoveis>
```